# How to find a location of a cell which contain certain text?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to find the location of a cell that contains certain text. For instance, I would like to find cell number of the cell which contains `Functionviel`,

For example, a cell is: `Functionviel     : 1.59545e+07 EUR`,  whose cell number let's say `A19845`. Then using that I will perform certain operations like: `=TRIM(MID($A$19845, 28, 7))*POWER(10,7)`

How can I find which cell includes `Functionviel`?

Comment: Do you expect only one cell to have that text? Can multiple have it?

Comment: Only one cell will contain it in whole column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using these definitions:

```
A4:A12 is our array to search. 
B1 has the text you want to find.
```

This formula will search your range for the desired text and return the cell address. It's using a wildcard search.

```
=CELL("address", INDEX($A$4:$A$12,MATCH("*"&$B$1&"*",$A$4:$A$12,0)))
```

Index + Match provides advanced lookup capabilities in Excel.

**UPDATE**

However, that will only get you the address and not play well within your formula. If you want the actual value (thanks BigBen for pointing that out), then just slightly tweak as:

```
=TRIM(MID(INDEX($A$1:$A$20000,MATCH("*"&$B$1&"*",$A$1:$A$20000,0)), 28, 7))*POWER(10, 7)
```

Perhaps the tricky part is how you know to use 28 and 7 in your MID logic. Will that always be the same?

Comment: @BigBen Well, I answered the original question, but I'm not certain this is what would work for the use case. Thinking about this now, as I think he/she wants the value not the cell.

Comment: Well, good to hear. I will stop the thinking.

Comment: It finds it but I cannot simply write `=TRIM(MID(=CELL("address", INDEX($A$1:$A$20000,MATCH("*"&$L$1&"*",$A$1:$A$20000,0))), 28, 7))*POWER(10,7)`

Comment: Remove the `=` sign before `CELL` but I fear this is going to give you the MID from cell address, not the mid from the cell value.

Comment: Even after I delete second `=` , it gives `#VALUE! `Error

Comment: @BigBen Feel free to add as an answer and I'll remove mine.

Comment: Thank you very much, guys! It works for my first use case. But in a second use case, I need to find `Mipgap` but it finds some other stuff includes `MIPGAP`. Is there any way to make `B1` case sensitive or make it find the last correspondence of `B1`?

Answer (score 0):

This is a index match combo solution. see
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2609-excel-lookup-return-cell-address.html
for some details.

There are a whole bunch of other detail to turn this into something useful.
Your example your data was in one column and you used fixed string positions to cut them out.  I would recommend an alternative.

The data as you have it should be split into 3 columns.  Tag , value, Currency
The tag is what the index match solution will search on.
The resulting address will have to be decomposed into column and row labels.
The column has to "incremented" to point to the next column to the right.
The new column and row can be concatenated and used in a indirect function to get its value.

[image: Data in sheet and flipped to see formulas]

PS I did this as fully exploded formula to see the actions at
each step.  When you understand what was done you can hide the intermediate columns.  You could combine them into a monstrosity of a formula that would be hard to understand in two weeks let alone in two years.